# Grails + Shiro plugin fails on error creating ShiroFilters cannot resolve reference to bean transactionManager

Tags: grails, shiro

After installing the Shiro plugin (v 1.1.3) in a Grails (v 1.3.7) application and using  *grails shiro-quick-start --prefix="Sec"* to bootstrap the different Shiro classes grails run-app fails with the stack trace shown below.

Anybody got an idea what exactly is going wrong?

When staring the application the following exception is shown:

> Running Grails application..
>   2011-05-09 16:14:31,209 [main] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error
>   executing bootstraps: Error creating
>   bean with name
>   'org.apache.shiro.grails.ShiroFilters':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'shiroAnnotationHandlerService':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting
>   bean property 'transactionManager';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No bean named 'transactionManager' is
>   defined
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.apache.shiro.grails.ShiroFilters':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'shiroAnnotationHandlerService':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting
>   bean property 'transactionManager';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No bean named 'transactionManager' is
>   defined   at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
>     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)  at
>   RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'shiroAnnotationHandlerService':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting
>   bean property 'transactionManager';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No bean named 'transactionManager' is
>   defined   ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
>   No bean named 'transactionManager' is
>   defined   ... 23 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the Hibernate plugin, and only then the Shiro plugin.

The transactionManager bean is defined by the Hibernate plugin, so it was quite normal that the Shiro plugin classes could not reference the transactionManager bean.

Shame on me!

Comment: I think the Hibernate plugin's installed with Grails by default?

Comment: I started with declaring the plugins in BuildConfig.groovy instead of using application.properties? It can be I mistakenly forgot to copy the hibernate plugin from application.properties to BuildConfig.groovy before installing the Shiro plugin.